# How to place junit/phpunit tests in a methods javadoc/phpdoc docblock?

Tags: junit, phpunit, javadoc, nose, phpdoc

I remember having seen something like:

```
/**
 * ("world") -> "hello world"
 * ("") -> "hello "
 */
public static myFunc(in) {
  return "hello " + in;
}
```

So you can place trivial tests directly in the documentation block of a function. Your test framework finds these tests and executes them.

But I can't remember whether I saw this in Java, Python, PHP or JavaScript. Do you know any tools in any language who do this? Is there a special name for this thing?

I already found it in [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/JavadocAssertionTestSuite.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python it is called [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html%20doctest):

> The doctest module searches for pieces of text that look like interactive Python sessions, and then executes those sessions to verify that they work exactly as shown.

Comment: Thank you. Searching for doctest and java/php finally gave good results.